# Problemas con un Array asociativo en php

Tags: php

Tengo Una clase libro que tiene entre sus atributos un array donde se deben guardar los registros de cada prestamo que se hace del libro(codigo lector, fecha prestamo, fecha estimada devolución y fecha real devolucion).
Para ello utilizo primero la función `prestar()` que crea un array asociativo para cada parametro en la ultima posicion del mismo, dando lugar por tanto a un array bidimensional de registros de prestamos. La función `prestar()` rellena todos los campos del registro del prestamo, salvo el ultimo `Freal` que debe ser rellenado por la función `devolver()` y ahi es donde esta el problema, utilizo la funcion `end()` para acceder al ultimo campo del array pero aunque no me da error e incluso haciendo `echo` efectivamente se ve que accede a esa ultima posición no me rellena el campo que me falta.

```
final class libro extends publicacion implements prestable{
    private $prestado = false;
    private $ArrayPrestamos = array();

    public function __get($atributo) {
        if(property_exists(__CLASS__, $atributo)){
            return $this->$atributo;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function __set($nombre, $valor) {
        $this->$nombre=$valor;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return parent::__toString()." | ¿Prestado? ".(boolval($this->prestado) ? 'Si' : 'No');
    }

    public function prestar($codLector) {
        try{
            if(!$this->prestado) {
                $f_actual = date('d-m-Y');
                $f_stimada = strtotime('+10 day' , strtotime($f_actual));
                $f_stimada = date('d-m-Y' , $f_stimada);
                $this->ArrayPrestamos[] = array ("codL"=>$codLector, "Fprestamo"=>$f_actual, "Fstimada"=>$f_stimada, "Freal"=>'');
                $this->prestado = true;
            } else {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("ERROR: El libro ya esta prestado");
             } 
        }
        catch(InvalidArgumentException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   

    }

    public function devolver() {
        try{
            if($this->prestado) {
                $f_actual = date('d-m-Y');
                end($this->ArrayPrestamos)["Freal"] = $f_actual;
                $this->prestado = false;
            } else {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("ERROR: El libro no esta prestado");
             } 
        }
        catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function EstaPrestado() {
        return $this->prestado;
    }

    public function MuestraArray() {
        return var_dump($this->ArrayPrestamos); 
    }


}
```

Y aqui esta la prueba de ejecución:

```
echo "<p>--- Creamos el libro \"Titulo Libro 1\"</p>";
$book1 = new libro (4, "Titulo Libro 1", 1997);
$book1->prestar(44);
$book1->devolver();
echo "<p>".$book1->MuestraArray()."</p>";
echo $book1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque la función `end` devuelve el valor del último elemento, como dice la documentación, si devolviese la referencia al último elemento podrias hacerlo como lo escibiste, prueba de la siguiente manera

```
end($this->ArrayPrestamos);
$key = key($this->ArrayPrestamos);
$this->ArrayPrestamos[$key]["Freal"] = $f_actual;
```

o, también

```
$ultimo = array_pop($this->ArrayPrestamos);
$ultimo["Freal"] = $f_actual;
$this->ArrayPrestamos[] = $ultimo;
 // o
array_push($this->ArrayPrestamos, $ultimo);
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que con la función `end` no podés hacer cambios sobre el valor devuelto. Para eso tenés que acceder al elemento a través de su clave.
Algo así, para tomar el último del array:

```
$this->ArrayPrestamos[count($this->ArrayPrestamos) - 1]["Freal"] = $f_actual;
```

Comment: Al final utilice  `$clave = key($this->ArrayPrestamos);
     $this->ArrayPrestamos[$clave]["Freal"] = $f_actual;` pero Gracias de todas formas.